# selecting with regex content between two points

Tags: javascript, regex

I always have a hard time with regex..
I'm trying to select the text between (taking into acount the before and after)

```
'window.API=' and ';' //for window.API= '--API--';
```

and other cases like:

```
'window.img_cdn=' and ';' //for window.img_cdn= '--imgCDN--';
```

any tips on witch regex concepts I should use would be a great help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the content between 'xx' you can use a regex like this:

```
'(.*?)'
```

**[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/bL5uT6/1)**

For the sample text:

```
window.API= '--API--';
window.img_cdn= '--imgCDN--';
```

You will capture:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [13-20] `--API--`
MATCH 2
1.  [40-50] `--imgCDN--`
```

[image]

The javascript code you can use is:

```
var re = /'(.*?)'/g; 
var str = 'window.API= \'--API--\';\nwindow.img_cdn= \'--imgCDN--\';';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

On the other hand, if you specifically want to capture the content for only those entries, then you can use this regex:

```
window\.(?:API|img_cdn).*?'(.*?)'
```

Comment: What is this `m.index === re.lastIndex` magic? When I used regex `while(m = re.exec(input)) { /*access m[0] */; }` worked just fine.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I'm not a js dev, I added the coded generated by regex101 provided in the link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match any text between a `<some string>=` sign and a semicolon, here you go:

`(?:[\w\.]+\s*=\s')(.+)(?:';)$`

This regex pattern will match a full string if an escaped apostrophe is present in the string: `//for window.img_cdn = '--imgCDN and \'semicolon\'--';`

JavaScript code:

```
var re = /(?:[\w\.]+\s*=\s')(.+)(?:';)$/gm;
var str = '//for window.img_cdn= \'--imgCDN--\';\n//for window.img_cdn = \'--imgCDN and semicolon = ;;;--\';';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // view results
}
```

The required text is in the 1st captured group. In case there is a semicolon in the text you are looking for, you will correctly match it due to the `$` anchor.

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/lI2kO0/6)